# How to plot logarithmic scales

Tags: number-representation, logarithmic-scale

How can a simple logarithmic number line be drawn between any 2 integer values?

[image: logarithmic number line of integer values]

The closest function I found in the documentation is [`LogLinearPlot[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LogLinearPlot.html) and I've been racking my brains trying to figure out how to do this with no luck...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way is to plot the function `0` against a log axis.

```
LogLogPlot[0, {t, 1, 12}, Axes -> {True, False}, Ticks -> {Range[12]}]
```

[image]

or, changing the numbers

```
LogLogPlot[0, {t, 64, 96}, Axes -> {True, False}, Ticks -> {Range[64, 96]}]
```

[image]

The `Axis` function turns off the vertical axis (because you just want the number line) and the `Ticks` specifies where you want the tick marks. As a further example (to see the appropriate syntax), here is

```
 LogLogPlot[0, {t, 1.07, 1.44}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
         Ticks -> {{1.07, 1.15, 1.20, 1.29, 1.38, 1.44}}]
```

[image]

Note the double parentheses in the `Ticks` list. This is because `Ticks` is really a list of x-ticks and y-ticks (but since in this case, we aren't plotting any y's, so it is empty).

Comment: What if instead of a range of integers there is a list of irrational numbers?

As `LogLogPlot` generates a plot of `0` as function of `t` from `1` to `1.5` for example, the number list doesn't seem to fit here. `FindDivisions` didn't help either so I guess it has to do with setting the ticks according to my defined list. I tried `Ticks -> {1.07,1.15,1.20,1.29,1.38,1.44}`, also with `List` but this doesn't work.

Comment: I added this example, above. Note the double parentheses in the `Ticks` list. This is because `Ticks` is really a list of x-ticks and y-ticks (but since in this case, we aren't plotting any y's, it's empty).

Answer (score 5):

And another way:

```
logLine[min_, max_] := Module[{lines, labels},

  lines = Line[{{Log[#], -1}, {Log[#], 1}}] & /@ Range[min, max];

  labels = Text[#, {Log[#], 1.7}] & /@ Range[min, max];

  Graphics[{
    labels,
    Line[{{Log[min], 0}, {Log[max], 0}}],
    lines
    }, AspectRatio -> 1/10
   ]

  ]
```

We have then that `logLine[1,12]` yields

[image: logline]

To plot an arbitrary range we could use the following function:

```
logLineRange[range_] := Module[{lines, labels},

  lines = Line[{{Log[#], -1}, {Log[#], 1}}] & /@ range;

  labels = Text[#, {Log[#], 1.7}] & /@ range;

  Graphics[{
    labels,
    Line[{{Log[Min[range]], 0}, {Log[Max[range]], 0}}],
    lines
    }, AspectRatio -> 1/10
   ]

  ]
```

Having defined that function, we can then do this:

```
logLineRange[{1.07, 1.15, 1.20, 1.29, 1.38, 1.44}]
```

[image: logline2]

Comment: Mathematica can't seem to plot this; tried replacing `min` and `max` with `1` and `12`, both with and without the `_` sign, only in the first line then all over the code - it returns nothing.

I'm also interested in a version where the range of integers is replaced with a list of irrational numbers - for example `1.07,1.15,1.20,1.29,1.38,1.44`.

Comment: @Bogdan The code block is just the definition for the function. To actually plot a scale you write `logLine[1,12]` for example. I added another function which takes an arbitrary range, you can have both those functions defined simultaneously as they take a different number of arguments. I added an example of how to use the second function as well.

Comment: Thank you, everything is clear. How come your first example doesn't work for 1 to 10? Try `logLine[1,10]`

Comment: @Bogdan It works for me, don't know why it would not work for you. :/

Comment: Very strange, indeed. The Holy Restart solved it. As a side note, your second code can also be used for plotting a specific range with `logLineRange[Range[1,12]]`

Answer (score 2):

Create unit-sized number lines with tick mapping function `f` for a list of values `vals`:

```
numberLine[f_, vals_List] :=
    With[{pos = Rescale[f /@ vals], tick = 1/50},
        Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
            MapThread[
                {Line[{{#1, -tick}, {#1, tick}}], 
                 Text[#2, {#1, 2 tick}]} &, {pos, vals}]}, 
            PlotRange -> {{-2 tick, 1 + 2 tick}, {3 tick, -tick}}]]

GraphicsColumn[{numberLine[Log, Range[12]], 
    numberLine[Identity, Range[64, 96]]}]
```

[image]

EDIT: Apparently both number lines in the original question are logarithmic, while mine above are logarithmic and linear. This is easy to fix, of course.

Comment: Yes it is. On the last line, replace `Identity` with `Log`.

I would also like to use your code to plot a version where the range of integers is replaced with a list of irrational numbers - for example `1.07,1.15,1.20,1.29,1.38,1.44`.

Comment: @Bogdan You can replace `vals` with any list of numeric quantity; for instance, `{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, E, Pi, E^2, Pi^2, Sqrt[2], 5 Sin[1], 40/7}`. Also, you can use `Reals`, such as `1.07`. There might be some issues with this (solvable by `Hold`, or multipliers used with `tick` I believe), but for simpler expressions, it's just fine.

Comment: I can't seem to make this work; just replaced `vals` with the list - only in the first line then again in the second. I'm still searching the documentation to figure out what's wrong. This is the first time i use Mathematica; different versions of the code are my very best tutorial. Thank you.

Comment: @Bogdan Run `Clear[numberLine]`, re-evaluate above definition of `numberLine` and try out `numberLine[Identity, {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, E, Pi, E^2, Pi^2, Sqrt[2], 5 Sin[1], 40/7}]`. Maybe I was a bit vague. For beginners, `Range[12]`, for instance, generates list corresponding to `{1, 2, 3, ..., 12}`. :)

Answer (score 2):

`Rescale[Log@v](b-a)+a` will space any list `v` of positive values logarithmically over the interval `[a,b]`.

```
v = Range[12]; Transpose@{N@Rescale[Log@v]*11+1, v}

{1.,      1}
{4.06837, 2}
{5.86326, 3}
{7.13674, 4}
{8.12454, 5}
{8.93163, 6}
{9.61401, 7}
{10.2051, 8}
{10.7265, 9}
{11.1929, 10}
{11.6148, 11}
{12.,     12}

v = Range[64,96,4]; Transpose@{N@Rescale[Log@v]*32+64, v}

{64.,     64}
{68.7846, 68}
{73.2956, 72}
{77.5627, 76}
{81.6109, 80}
{85.4615, 84}
{89.1329, 88}
{92.6411, 92}
{96.,     96}
```